# mulesoft sftp Auth fail - password with special characters

Tags: mule-studio

I am having a problem with mulesoft SFTP outbound. I am keep on getting Auth fail from Mulesoft to connect to SFTP server. My password has special characters. I tried to change them to URL encode, but couldn't get through. My password is like $$xyz123. I am also trying to use the private key file with the passphrase, which also has the special characters. Can anyone please help to resolve this.
Here is my sftp outbound endpoint:

```
<sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="111.11.111.111" port="22" path="/cygdrive/d/SFTPROOT/dev/" user="user" password="%24%24xyz123" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SFTP"  outputPattern="#[sessionVars.originalFileName]"/>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried to SSH to the host and make sure it is working?  Then try to SFTP from the command line and make sure it is working.  There is a known issue with SFTP if your profile generates output when you log in.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, Actually the same credentials are working well with WinSCP and Filezilla client. The problem is only with Mule sftp outbound.

Comment: OK, but make sure it works with SFTP.  The other programs are not the same, even though they are very close.  Special characters in your password should not be a problem unless they are multi-byte characters.  You can always escape them with '\' if you think mulesoft is evaluating them ""\$\$xyz123" or "\\\$\\\$xyz123" depending on if there are one or two levels of evaluation.

Comment: Now I am trying with an sFTP server with plain password. That connection is good. But when I add the identity file (.ppk) I am getting "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail". Note that this ppk file doesn't have any passphrase.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe the ppk file should work?  Normally a ppk file has to be converted to a pem file before it will work with SSH.  And you need the entry in authorized_keys in the users home directory to open the SSH connection using the identity file.